# "Bundled python" in command console after reinstall blender 2.8, and unusual console command shows up every time

Tags: command-line, installation

[image]Reinstall blender.  and "found bundled python" shows up every time.

Is something wrong?  If so, how can I fix it?

Thank you

edit1 added the unusual console command, something to do with rigging

Comment: Nothing wrong, a bundled python distribution comes with each Blender. This is normal. What is the *unusual console command* ?

Comment: Thank you for your help.  As for the unusual console, I ll add the pic into question for clarity.  Thx again.